# Why is wine installed automatically with i386 AND amd64 versions in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, wine

When I install wine in a fresh 12.04 ubuntu the installer , synaptic in my case, insists on installing both versions: i386 and amd64 ...

Why? I don't get this - and it seems to get me into trouble when installing stuff via wine on my 64bit system wine looks for gnomekeyring libs in the directory for i386 libs!

When I am running a 64bit system there should be no need for wine i386, should there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I am running a 64bit system there should be no need for wine i386, should there?

Wine i386 is necessary to run 32-bit Windows programs -- which is MOST of them, unless you have an explicit 64-bit version, and even then, the installers for those are often 32-bit.